# How to read pdf file directly from github (without downloading or fetching it from github)?

Tags: python, pdf, github, pypdf

I understand that we could extract text from pdf file.

for example,

```
import pandas as pd
import PyPDF2

# =============================================================================
# Extracting from pdf files
# =============================================================================
pdfFileObj = open(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Sentiment_Analysis\Urea Weekly Report 01-07-2016.pdf', 'rb')

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
totalpage = pdfReader.numPages

pg = [''] * (totalpage-2-2)
for i in [x for x in range(2,totalpage-2) if x != 7]:
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    pg[i-2] = pageObj.extractText().replace("\n","").lower()
```

How can I do the similar thing, but now the pdf file resides in github?

I know we could do this with excel file (without downloading)

```
import pandas as pd
meg = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/James-smarttradz/arimax/master/MEG_marketprice_ICIS.csv')
```

For example, my file is located in 
https://github.com/James-smarttradz/sentiment/blob/master/Urea%20Weekly%20Report%2001-07-2016.pdf

Comment: Have you taken a look at a library like `requests` to fetch the file?

Comment: hi oliver, i know i could fetch or download the file and complete the operation above, i would like to know if i could perform the operation directly on the pdf file without fetching or downloading it like the similar code for excel above.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this pdf file as a firt step :

```
 import wget
    url = "https://github.com/James-smarttradz/sentiment/blob/master/Urea%20Weekly%20Report%2001-07-2016.pdf"
    wget.download(url, 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Sentiment_Analysis\Urea Weekly Report 01-07-2016.pdf')
```

And continue with your previous code to make the necessary operation

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, i know i could download the file and complete the operation above, i would like to know if i could perform the operation directly on the pdf file on github without fetching or downloading it like the code for excel above.